# What do I call the thing that signifies a new command line in the Linux terminal and can I customize it?

Tags: linux, terminal, customization

[image]

I'm getting accustomed to Linux (very new to it) and I was wondering if there is anything I can do to customize the root@kali:-# part (i know this signifies where I am in my computer) but I would like to change the colors and the format it is displayed in!

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: It's called the "prompt" and it's controlled with the `PS1` shell variable – see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt), the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) and the [tag:ps1] tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks! you should make that an answer, ill upvote and accept :)

Comment: I actually voted to close the question as "needs more focus" – "how do I customize my prompt?" is too broad, IMO, and I wouldn't want to answer a question that is too broad. I can leave a wiki answer, though. I recommend you play around with `PS1` and come back with specific questions later on. Consider asking on [su] or [unix.se] instead of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the "prompt" and it's controlled with the `PS1` shell variable.

References:

- [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)
- [POSIX sh Shell Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)
- [Bash Prompt HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/)
- [ps1](/questions/tagged/ps1) tag on Stack Overflow